# Python ttk.Button -command, runs without button being pressed

Tags: python, function, button, ttk

I'm making a small script in python with ttk and I have a problem where a function runs where it shouldn't. The button code looks as follows:

```
btReload = ttk.Button(treeBottomUI, text="Reload", width=17, command=loadModelTree(treeModel))
btReload.pack(side="left")
```

and the function is as this:

```
def loadModelTree(tree):
    print ("Loading models...")
    allModels = os.listdir(confModPath)
    for chunk in allModels:
        ...
```

For some reason, the function runs without the button being pressed. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Markus, yes, that's the right solution, but it is not because you can't use multi-argument commands in widget callouts. Consider, in your original code, `...command=loadModelTree(treeModel)...` is an *invocation* of the method. Lambda allows you to abstract the command so you can have an arbitrary number of arguments without confusing the interpreter by invoking it, e.g., `...command=lambda arg1=myarg1, arg2=myarg2, arg3=myarg3: myCallout(arg1, arg2, arg3)...`.

I hope that makes what is going on a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I found the answer, I'll answer my own question.
It appers that ttk.button commands does not support sending arguments to functions so the work around is to do as follows:

```
btReload = ttk.Button(treeBottomUI, text="Reload", width=17, command=lambda i=treeModel: loadModelTree(i))
btReload.pack(side="left")
```

Simple as pie!